# Node, Mongodb, Limiting updatemany to the first 500 entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way in node using the native mongodb driver to limit an update many operation only to the first 500 entries?

right now my update many line looks like this

```
col.updateMany({$exists : {available : false}}, {$set : {available : "na"}}, function(){});
```

Is there a way to limit the number of documents it searches and updates?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I have usually just use either a simple find or an aggregation query, save it to a variable and then update only those. And repeat.